# How do I tell SVN not to ignore .class files?

Tags: maven, svn, deployment, ignore, .class-file

Here's the situation.

I use Maven to manage dependencies and compile and deploy the project in development, and that's fine.

But in test and production, the machines don't have Maven, so I need some easy way to have compiled the project for manual deployment to Weblogic there.

My solution was to use Maven to compile the project as an exploded .war and commit that war to SVN.

For deployment in Test and Production you can just then check out the .war and deploy it.

Unfortunately SVN wants to ignore the .class files.

Can I tell it to not ignore them for this project?

The SVN config looks like:

```
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

So I can't see that .class files are ignored here.

Or do you have an alternative suggestion for compiling a war and deploying, that doesn't require Maven?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - That looks like the solution I'll be going for. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question is the real question.
Checking the derived artifacts into source control is never going to be the path.

Look into jenkins or some other continuous integration server.  You can have that machine build your war one time and then deploy that war to multiple environments.

You will likely want to publish the war somewhere - look into artifactory or nexus.
Then you can script your deploy to grab the latest snapshot or release.

Comment: Let's assume here that it's not possible to use any tools that I don't already have.

Comment: your best bet: get a new job.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see that .class files are ignored here

You **must** to know - Subversion have more than single way to define ignore-pattern for any PATH/IN/REPO

Except global definition in config, it can be properties `svn:ignore`|`svn:global-ignores` (SVN 1.8.*), defined in the context of repository-tree. You have to add .class file in WC and with `svn pg svn:ignore` + `svn pg svn:global-ignores -v --show-inherited-props` find the point of injection of ignoring in question

Comment: Sorry your first sentence doesn't make sense. Can you reread and edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered pushing the compiled WAR file to a Maven repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory? Test and Production systems could then pull down any built version of your project.